# Send non-tmux window to tmux

Tags: process, tmux

I have a few terminals open. I'd like to send the processes in those terminals to a `tmux` session rather than saving, closing, restarting under `tmux`, and then getting the process back to the state it's currently in.

How do I attach a running non-tmux process to a `tmux` session?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't.

Answer (score 5):

`reptyr` should do that job. See [github](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr)

Find out the process id of the job you want to transfer. I usually do this by typing

```
ps -p | grep programname
```

then go to the tmux session, window, pane, ... and insert:

```
reptyr PID
```

where `PID` is the process id you just found out.

This workflow should be scriptable.

If some message appears, that tells that it does not work:

```
Unable to attach to pid 4625: Operation not permitted
The kernel denied permission while attaching
...
```

Type in as root for allowing the above:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this but did not succeed.

Comment: @isomorphismes: I tried it too , now, worked like a charm. But, I had to execute `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` beforehand as root, since this operation was not allowed by default.